# Rails & Ransack Icon to Show Field is Sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm working on a requirement,for a Rails Application, to add an Icon to the Column Title for the list outcome from a Ransack form.
The icon should be something a double arrow head that is similar in style to the icons that Ransack appends to a column title to show it has been sorted by that column.  Something like this [Sortable Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBMZw.gif)The Ransack sort_asc or sort_desc icon should replace the sorting icon.
I've search the Ransack documentation, Stackoverflow and google in general to no avail.
Here is a fragment of the search list *.html.haml file.

```
%table.table.table-hover
    %thead
        %tr
            %th
                = sort_link(@query, :title)
            %th
                = sort_link(@query, :description)
            %th
                = sort_link(@query, :company_name, 'Company')
            %th
                = sort_link(@query, :shift)
            %th
                = sort_link(@query, :address_state)
            %th
                = sort_link(@query, :address_city)`and the direction of the sort.
```

Answer (score 4):

Ransack has configuration options for `custom_arrows`. You may use it in ransack initializer to override default arrows. For example:

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
    config.custom_arrows = {
      up_arrow: '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>',
      down_arrow: 'U+02193'
    }
  end
```

Comment: yes but is there a way to set an icon for the initial display of an unsorted column to show that it is sortable?

Comment: @PaulCaston Ransack does not support this behaviour. You will need to override `order_indicator` method in ransack FormHelper: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/6fcb16816236c6b987cd5d776bd9ed4364a0c939/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb#L211

Comment: Thanks @Slava.K just what I was looking for.

Comment: @PaulCaston you can now use default_arrow

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Slava.K, you can adjust the Ransack configuration in an initializer or override Ransack's FormHelper.

But if you want to do this manually in your view, you can! Use the `sort_url` helper to create the link, then check Ransack's `sorts` array to determine which sort is being used and what direction (asc/desc), then render the appropriate icon.

This example will display one of three icons (up/down/neutral) depending on the field if it was sorted or not, and which direction it was sorted. We will use the [fontawesome-sass gem](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) to render an icon but you can replace the `icon()` helper with whatever icon method/markup you want to use.

```rb
  # some_view.html.slim

  = link_to sort_url(@q, :name)

    # Display label
    span Name

    # Sort icon

    # Check if ransack applied a sort to this field
    - sort = @q.sorts.find {|s| s.name == 'name'}

    # Render appropriate icon (up/down/neutral)
    
    # If this column is sorted by 'asc' display 'sort-up' icon
    = icon(:fas, 'sort-up') if sort.present? and sort.dir == 'asc'

    # If this column is sorted by 'desc' display 'sort-down' icon
    = icon(:fas, 'sort-down') if sort.present? and sort.dir == 'desc'

    # If no sort is applied display a neutral icon
    = icon(:fas, 'sort') unless sort.present?
```

We can simplify the code above by using a ternary operator, like so...

```rb
  # some_view.html.slim

  = link_to sort_url(@q, :name)
    span Name
    - sort = @q.sorts.find {|s| s.name == 'name'}
    = icon :fas, sort.present? ? (sort.dir == 'asc' ? 'sort-up' : 'sort-down') : 'sort'
```

If you want to get really fancy and keep your view's DRY, you could create a helper method similar to Ransacks `sort_url` or `sort_link` and place this markup into it. It could look something like this...

```rb
  # some_helper.rb

  def custom_sort_link(search_object, attribute, *args)
    link_to sort_url(search_object, attribute, *args) do
      sort = search_object.sorts.find {|s| s.name == attribute.to_s}
      content_tag(:span, attribute.to_s.capitalize) + icon(:fas, sort.present? ? (sort.dir == 'asc' ? 'sort-up' : 'sort-down') : 'sort')
    end
  end
```

And then in your view, call `custom_sort_link` like so...

```rb
  # some_view.html.slim

  = custom_sort_link(@q, :name)
```

As a side note, if you have FontAwesome Pro, the duotone icons look way better. Just replace `:fas` with `:fad`.

Answer (score 0):

The default sorting icon can be implemented like this:

```
if defined?(Ransack)
  Ransack.configure do |config|
    config.custom_arrows = { default_arrow: '<i class="fa fa-sort"></i>' }
  end
end
```